# Is there a way to improve tile performance for cloud-based storage?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, amazon-s3

I am trying to use cloud-storage for GWC tiles. However performance is abysmal, no matter the tweaks or provider I'm using.

What I've tried:

- Providers: AWS, Wasabi
- Access: [S3 Plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/community/gwc-s3/index.html), File-system plugin with mounted drive using [goofy](https://github.com/kahing/goofys), File-system plugin with mounted drive using [s3fs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/s3fs)
- Preseeding tiles: using either of the above methods was too slow (max 128 tiles/sec). I found some success using the local drive to pre-seed, and then using [rclone](https://rclone.org/) to transfer to cloud with increased connections.
- Retrieving tiles: after pre-seeding, retrieval is between 300-600ms, even while using memory caching. Compared to local disk access, which is between 150-300ms.

If anyone has had success using cloud storage for GWC tiles, what was the trick that enabled it?

Comment: why would expect the cloud to be faster than a local disk? seeding speed is mostly limited by the cpu on the seeding machine not disk speed

Comment: @IanTurton, I don't expect it to be faster, I expect it to be usable and on-par, otherwise I think nobody would bother to develop a plug in for something that can't be used. The seeding speed I'm referring to the post compares the same seeding machine (same cpu), when used to seed local tiles and cloud-storage tiles.

Comment: you do understand that a community extension is designed as a demo or initial implementation - maybe you need to jump in as owner of the extension and help speed it up

Comment: Just to make sure, the server is located in the amazon cloud, and in the same region as the S3 bucket, right? Otherwise, slowness would be pretty normal....

Comment: @AndreaAime, no the server is not located in the same network. However, since rclone can actually write fast enough using multiple connections, shouldn't the rest of the mechanisms also be up to that speed? My hunch (emphasize on hunch), is that a) the plugin isn't opening up multiple connections and that b) goofy on the default settings have a connection cap which is less than rclone's, thus the less throughput.

Comment: Could be, initialization of the S3 client is here, if you feel like investigating and eventually offer a pull request with improvemenets: https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/blob/main/geowebcache/s3storage/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/s3/S3BlobStoreInfo.java#L352